# I did somethings with mount-manager.. and I have some small problems

Tags: fstab

I tried to automount partitions using mountmanager. But I don't know what I did.
Pls help. I may find a way to automount but what I need is different

I need my sda6 and sda7 to mount at /media. (But I entered /mnt in mountmanager).
Also some partitions are not showing in nautilus devices list.

```
My fdisk-l


Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2cf52cf4

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    51215219    25607578+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        51215281   312576704   130680712    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        51215283    71698094    10241406    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6        71698158   163862999    46082421    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       163863063   267530444    51833691    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       308496258   312576704     2040223+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       300111872   308494335     4191232   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      267532288   291723263    12095488   83  Linux
/dev/sda11      291725312   300109823     4192256   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4292 MB, 4292870144 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 521 cylinders, total 8384512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x39ee04e1

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I want to reset my fstab or mount settings for sda6 and sda7 and I need my device lists back to normal. Pls help

I can't upload images here. My nautilus Devices list shows
26GB Filesystem
10GB Filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a random suggestion, perhaps uninstall mountmanager and use a different utility? You're familiar with commandline, so perhaps use fstab and 'sudo mount -a' would do the trick for you?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I uninstalled mountmanager. Then I deleted the two entries - sda6 and sda7 from fstab. When restarted, nautilus devices list restored. And I used pysdm for automount.

Comment: `pysdm` has some issues - notably that when editing partition info in fstab, it adds a new line rather then editing the line already present.  This can assist in causing some ridiculously confusing problems.  Culling entries like you did is usually best.